# MVC Individual User Areas

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am doing a little project for FX traders that allows them to login to their own account and add the trades they have taken to their account, but I do not want other users to see this data, just their own data.

I have done some research but I am unsure on what to look for, would anyone be able to point me in the right direction? Is it something I will have to do with the Areas?

Comment: You don't need to use areas, just limit the data displayed based on who's logged in. Note that there are a number of laws and regulations around trading and the data around them you should be aware of and follow...

Comment: Areas in ASP.NET MVC are for grouping related routes, controllers. assets and files (e.g. `.aspx/cshtml` files) together. It has absolutely nothing to do with multi-tenant security scenarios, which is what you should be researching.